# Is it bad practice to surround an li tag with an a tag?

Tags: html, css, coding-style

For example:

```
<ul>
<a href="http://google.com"><li id="someId"></li></a>
...
...
...
</ul>
```

It's a quick hack for the existing css styling that I have. I am wondering if I should refactor it and place the a tags inside.

Comment: Why not put the a tag inside the li tag?  `<li id="someId"><a href="http://google.com">Item text</a></li>`

Comment: It's a hack, as mentioned in the question. The a has no content.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: While it is tempting do things like this, it can cause complications. Especially when updating your site.

Comment: Have you tried putting the anchor inside the list item and doing something along the lines of `display:block;height:100%;`?

Comment: @TheZ, who has time for such sillyness?! :) That's what I was referring to by refactoring.

Comment: @Ramin Oh okay, that is not what I got when you said refactoring, refactoring implied you'd be changing or rearranging the styles already in place instead of just adding a bit more ;)

Comment: It's really simple. The posted code is invalid. So you must fix it and I would call it bugfixing and not refactoring then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only element allowed as a child of a UL is an LI. You have to wrap the anchor around the contents of the LI, not the LI itself.

Even with HTML5's newfangled rules allowing anchors around block level elements, you still have to put the anchor within the LI itself.

Answer (score 10):

That's invalid HTML.

Don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

If the workaround is to make the `<li>` element clickable, you can set up a click handler on the `<li>` and with some css styling, make it look clickable. If you are using the jQuery library, you can do the following to associate a click handler to the `<li>` element.

```
$("#someId").click(function(e) {
    // handle the click event here
});
```

If you want it for all the `<li>` elements, you can set up the selector based on a css class which can be tagged on to all the `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example for HTML: But no idea what are you trying to accomplish.

```
<UL>
      <LI><A HREF="example.com">SomeID</A></LI>
</UL>
```

Comment: upper-case tags are depreciated